# Repeatedly getting 500 error on CGI script - frontend HTML works but not CGI [MySQL]

Tags: html, mysql, python-3.x, cgi

What I want is for a MySQL query that I wrote a few weeks ago to return values from a database based on an entered query.

Here is the HTML script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
        <p>
            Search by gene product name
        </p>
        <form name="search" method="post" action="XXXX-CGISCRIPT-XXXX">
            <input id="search_entry" type="text" name="search_entry">
            <input type="submit" value="Search">
        </form>

</body></html>
```

and here is the CGI script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import mysql.connector
import cgi
import jinja2
import re
from biocode import utils
import cgitb

def main():
    cgitb.enable()
    loadTemp = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath="./templates")
    environs = jinja2.Environment(loader=loadTemp)
    template = environs.get_template('search_template.html')

    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
    acc = form.getvalue('search_entry')
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'XXX', password = 'XXX', 
                    host = 'localhost', database = 'XXX_chado')
    # MySQL query
    qry = """SELECT f.uniquename, product.value, assem.uniquename, assem_type.name, g.fmin, g.fmax, g.strand
        FROM feature f
        JOIN cvterm polypeptide ON f.type_id=polypeptide.cvterm_id
        JOIN featureprop product ON f.feature_id=product.feature_id
        JOIN cvterm productprop ON product.type_id=productprop.cvterm_id
        JOIN featureloc g ON f.feature_id=g.feature_id 
        JOIN feature assem ON g.srcfeature_id=assem.feature_id 
        JOIN cvterm assem_type ON assem.type_id=assem_type.cvterm_id 
        WHERE polypeptide.name = 'polypeptide'
        AND productprop.name = 'gene_product_name'
        AND product.value LIKE %s;"""
    curs = conn.cursor()
    curs.execute(qry, ('%' + acc + '%',))

    for  (f.uniquename,  productprop.name)  in  curs:
        print(template.render(curs=curs, accs=acc))

    conn.close()
    curs.close()
```

I keep getting a 500 internal server error and I'm not quite sure why. My understanding is that `search_entry` on the HTML side (which works) is what the user enters into the search box to be handled by the CGI script. The query is then returned by

`form = cgi.FieldStorage() 
 acc = form.getvalue('search_entry')`

and then later passed by

`curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute(qry, ('%' + acc + '%',))`

to be used in the preceding MySQL query. The last few lines send variables over to the template (whose bridge I will cross when I get there) and close the connection.

My problem, I have trouble really understanding why it is that I keep getting the error message '500 Internal Server Error'. I have tried making several changes and caught many mistakes, as well as altered the formatting, but to no avail. If it was a template error, I don't think I would getting this server error, would I? I think it's a CGI error, and

`import cgitb
...
cgitb.enable()`

doesn't work, so I can't get a more detailed error message, regardless of where I place `cgitb.enable()` or if I have it print to file within the server.

Does anyone notice any obvious code errors that I could correct to at least stop getting the error? In the interest of full disclosure, this is for a school assignment.

Comment: Why the antiquated CGI mechanism instead of something current like [WSGI](https://www.fullstackpython.com/wsgi-servers.html) as used by things like [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com)? You'll get better logging with WSGI than you will with CGI, which makes debugging way faster.

Comment: @tadman I don't know, this is how our teacher wants us to do it. I'm open to using something better but our instructor is teaching us about CGI and Jinja so I'm just going along with it. Also, I'm not sure what is and isn't available on the server.

Comment: That's kind of discouraging as CGI fell out of style almost twenty years ago. Hopefully you can find out where this is logging errors so you can identify what problems your code might have. You may even try launching it in WSGI mode just to debug, then CGI later if that's a requirement for the assignment. The good news is that query uses proper placeholder values, so that's a plus.

Comment: The course server does not have WSGI as a module. I tried running the script on the command line and found out many of the errors had to do with hidden characters. Still doesn't work though. Thanks for your help nonetheless.